# Creayting a column chart for all the columns in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create column chart for all the columns in a worksheet. For the first 3 columns the code run well but from column 4 onward it showed an invalid parameter error. I have highlighted the error in the code for reference.

```
Sub chart_builder()
'
' chart_builder Macro
'

'

For Count = 1 to 56

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(233, Count + 1)).Select

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(233, Count + 1))
    If Count <> 1 Then
        For j = 1 To Count - 1
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete **"I am getting an invalid parameter error here**"
        Next
    End If
        ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Count + 1).Value

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: please mark the other two questionS of yours as answered according to [THIS INFORMATION](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: are data structure exactly the same for all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this version of your internal loop (see comment inside the code)

```
For j =( Count - 1) to 1 Step -1

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete 'When deleting do it from last element to firest

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same program charting all the columns in a worksheet and moving it into a new sheet with the header as the sheet name.
you might want to check if this will work for you?
Apologies, i'm having a hard time debugging your code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Create_Chart()

Dim ws, wschart As Worksheet, ch As Chart, lrow, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")

For i = 0 To 2 'this depends how many column you have which can also be made dynamic
    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).Offset(0, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Set ch = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=.Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value)
        ch.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ch.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("A1:A" & lrow).Offset(0, i)
        Set ch = Nothing
    End With
Next i

Set ws = nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this gives you additional idea to accomplish what you want.